# How to decltype template method C++?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++20, c++-concepts

I write interfaces through concepts for implementation validation.

There are no problems with conventional methods:

```
// Interface realization
struct Realization
{
    int* TestMethod(const std::string& aStr)
    {
        return (int *) aStr.c_str();
    }
};

// Concept
template <typename T>
concept IRealization = std::is_same_v<decltype(&T::TestMethod), int* (T::*)(const std::string&)>;

// and then, for example
void Check()
{
    static_assert(IRealization<Realization>)
}
```

but when I try to write a similar check for a template method:

```
// Interface realization
struct Realization
{
    template <typename T>
    int* TemplateMethod(const T& aStr)
    {
        return (int *) aStr.c_str();
    }
};
```

, I run into a problem of dectype a template method, because I cant write

```
decltype(&RealizationImpl::TemplateMethod)
```

(at the time of checking the interface, I do not know the type that will be substituted)

Please tell me, can I somehow get the signature of the template function without type, or otherwise solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: You can not obtain fucntion prototype without instantiation. You will need to add another template parameter to the concept because the concept will not need to test `T` but `T<U>`. `T<U1>` may succeed but `T<U2>` may fail.

Comment: Also side note to the question: What is `TestMethod` supposed to accomplish? Best case, if alignment matches, it returns a pointer that you are not allowed to dereference before casting it back to `char*` and worst case, if alignment doesn't match, it returns a pointer with unspecified value that is never usable.

Comment: `template <typename T> template <typename U> concept IRealization = std::is_same_v<decltype(&T::template TestMethod<U>), int* (T::*)(const U&)>;` won't compile so not sure of any other way..

Comment: @walnut TestMethod carries no logical meaning, it is just an example. You are right, I should have come up with a more adequate example

Answer (score 4):

You should not write concepts like this. A concept should never check for something as specific as a member function with an exact signature. A concept should instead say that, given an instance of the type in question, I should be able to do `i.memberFunc(...)`, where `...` is the list of parameters.

For example, your "IRealization" concept (please don't prefix concepts with `I`. Concepts are *not* interfaces) ought to say "`T` must have a member function which can be called given a `std::string` argument and results in something which is convertible to an `int`." That would look like:

```
template <typename T>
concept IRealization = requires(T t, std::string str)
{
  { t.TestMethod(str) } -> convertible_to<int>;
};
```

This allows the user to provide a `TestMethod` that takes, for example, `std::string_view` instead of `std::string`. There's no point in being so incredibly restrictive on the type.

A concept that checks for `T` having a member function which is callable with some type `U` would have to be templated on both `T` and `U`:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
concept IRealization = requires(T t, U u)
{
  { t.TestMethod(u) } -> convertible_to<int>;
};
```

Comment: "*Concepts are not interfaces*" - well, they do seem to enable similar type safety and selection when compared to, for example, Java interfaces. Care to elaborate on that, please? Additionally, I am very unfamiliar with `concept`'s syntax, but I believe that in your second snippet, `;` is a typo. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Fureeish: "*well, they do seem to enable similar type safety and selection when compared to, for example, Java interfaces.*" The biggest difference is this: which interfaces a type implements is defined as an explicit part of the type itself. By contrast, you cannot look at a type and know which concepts it satisfies. Indeed, you can define new concepts which old types satisfy; that's not possible for an interface, not unless you insert the interface in the type hierarchy.

Comment: There are many more. For instance a concept doesn't need to operate on one type. You can have a concept that says "this type has a bigger size than this type".

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with adding another type to the concept?

```cpp
// Concept
template <typename T, typename U>
concept IRealization = std::is_same_v<decltype(&T::template TestMethod<U>), int* (T::*)(const U&)>;
```

For instance.

You could even make it prettier by creating a typedef -

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
using FuncT = decltype(&T::template TestMethod<U>);
```